# Using not exists with Phql in Phalcon Framework

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to write a short query with [phql](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html). I'm selecting everything from one table and have a where clause declaring that another table can't have a record connected to this table. Here's the raw sql query that works fine when run against my db, which is Mysql.

```
select * from application a
where not exists (select distinct 1 from preapproval p where p.application_id = a.id)
```

So on to trying to write this in [phql](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html), I've been trying different things, but here's what I've ended up with.

Note: If I run this without the where clause it works, selecting all records from the 'application' table.

```
$manager = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->getShared("modelsManager");

$data = $manager
    ->createBuilder()
    ->from(['a' => '\Models\Application'])
    ->where('not exists (select distinct 1 from [\Models\Preapproval] where [\Models\Preapproval].application_id = a.id)')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

The exception being thrown is:

```
Syntax error, unexpected token SELECT, near to ' distinct 1 from [\Models\Preapproval] where [\Models\Preapproval].application_id = a.id)', when parsing: SELECT [a].* FROM [\Models\Application] AS [a] WHERE not exists (select distinct 1 from [\Models\Preapproval] where [\Models\Preapproval].application_id = a.id) (190)
```

So on to the question, **how do I write a where not exists clause in [phql](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Phalcon is not always able to parse complex queries using PhQL query builder.

However in this particular case you can do a leftJoin with condition:

```
/** @var ModelManager $manager */
$manager = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->getShared("modelsManager");
$data = $manager->createBuilder()
    ->columns('\Models\Application.*')
    ->from('\Models\Application')
    ->leftJoin('\Models\Preapproval', '\Models\Preapproval.application_id = \Models\Application.id')
    ->andWhere('\Models\Preapproval.id IS NULL')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

This may or may not have a negative or positive impact on performance depending on your database index cardinality.

Comment: That's basically the same thing I ended up doing, I'll accept this as an answer. I think it's the closest we're gonna get to a good solution. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. You can either use [raw sql](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#using-raw-sql), left joins (in my case i had to use many 'join ON' conditions) or you can [try this](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1082/sneaking-in-subqueries-into-phql#C4020)